# Enumerate all valid orders of subset sums

Tags: algorithms, enumeration, subset-sum

Given an positive integer $n$, we define an *order of subset sums* (or simply, an *order*, when there is no ambiguity) to be a sequence of **all** subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. For example, when $n=2$, the sequence $\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}$ is an order.

We call an order $S_1,\ldots,S_{2^n}$ *valid* if there exist real numbers $0<x_1<\cdots<x_n$ such that $\sum_{i\in S_1}x_i<\cdots<\sum_{i\in S_{2^n}}x_i$. For example, when $n=2$, the sequence $\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}$ is a valid order, but the sequence $\emptyset,\{1\},\{1,2\},\{2\}$ is not because we cannot make $x_1+x_2<x_2$.

The question is, given $n$, how to enumerate all possible valid orders. To output an order $S_1,\ldots,S_{2^n}$, it is sufficient to output an algorithm that generates this order, i.e., an algorithm with no input (the parameter $n$ is built-in) that outputs $S_1,\ldots,S_{2^n}$ in order, as long as the algorithm runs in $O(n2^n)$ time. Even so, this problem still cannot be solved in time polynomial in $n$, because there may be exponentially many valid orders, thus an algorithm running in exponential time is welcome.

A trivial algorithm would be to iterate over all possible orders, and check for each one if it is valid. But I cannot even find an (efficient) way to check if an order is valid.

Comment: As far as I understand, you are asking about Boolean Lattice (please see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure)), where you introduce a **total** order using an additional vector $X=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$. Your "valid order" is used to be called a *chain*. It's unclear why you define this total order using *existence* of $X$ only - it will depend on **values** in $X$. Also for totally ordered set there will be only one chain (provided that there are no pairwise equal elements).

Comment: @HEKTO Yes, I'm essentially seeking for a method to enumerate all *possible* chains as the values of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ vary. However, I don't understand how this problem is related to the Boolean algebra since this problem talks about orders of subsets.

Comment: If you want to know what happens with chains when the vector $X$ varies - then you should clarify your question. The set of subsets of a finite set *is* Boolean algebra *and* Boolean lattice (= $n$-dimensional hypercube), where each node is a Boolean $n$-tuple

Comment: @HEKTO I now understand the relation between subsets and Boolean algebra, but how can this help solve the problem? I don't know how to clarify since I don't know the definition of "chain" and I have a sense that your "chain" is not equivalent to my "valid order". Maybe it is more proper to say that I'm essentially seeking for a method to enumerate all possible total orders as the values of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ vary. I think the question statement is clear though it does not mention any concept about boolean lattice.

Comment: Chain is a totally ordered subset of a poset. Maximum chain is a chain, which is not contained in any other chain. Totally ordered set consists of a single maximum chain.

Comment: @xskxzr Let order $o$ start with $\emptyset$. A trivial condition for $o$ to be a valid order is for any $4$ sets $A, B, C, D$ in $o$ such that $A\cap B=C\cap D=\emptyset$, $A\prec_o B$ and $C\preceq_o D$, we also have $A\cup C\prec_o B\cup D$. Are you aware of an invalid order $o$ that satisfies that trivial condition?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one algorithm that runs in doubly exponential time -- so probably useless.  In other words, this answer is probably not useful.

You can check whether an order is valid in $2^{O(n)}$ time (i.e., $\text{poly}(2^n)$ time) by reducing to linear programming: you obtain $2^n+n-2$ linear inequalities in $n$ variables, and you can test for feasibility in time polynomial in the number of inequalities and variables.  Then, enumerating over all possible sums and checking if each is valid would yield a $(2^n)! 2^{O(n)} = 2^{n 2^n + O(2^n)}$ time algorithm.  This will be ridiculously slow in practice.

---

To improve this, you could use an iterative pruning / branch-and-bound style algorithm.  Given a prefix $S_1,\dots,S_k$ of an order, we can test whether it is valid using linear programming as above.  If it is not, we don't consider any order that starts with this prefix.  In other words, do breadth-first search: first choose $S_1$, then choose $S_2$, then choose $S_3$, and so on, at each step checking whether the prefix obtained so far is valid.

This may still be extremely slow, as there is the possibility that a prefix $S_1,\dots,S_k$ is valid but there is no way to complete it to a full order $S_1,\dots,S_{2^n}$ that is valid, so this might do a lot of wasted work.